# I want to connect web3 wallet using cookie.(walletconnect/client)

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, wallet-connect

I want to keep connection info and connect web3 wallet using cookie.
I tried this code.

```
JSON.stringfy(connector);
```

But stringfy function can't use for function in object.
If we use stringfy function to some functions in object, We lost the variable about the functions.

How can I connect wallet only using variable that can be inserted into cookie?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Saving connection information is not possible as it contains circular json.

For me, the work around was to create walletconnect instanace as page loads.

```js
const a = async () => {
      await provider.enable();
      let web3 = initWeb3(provider);
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const address = accounts[0];
      setConnector(provider);  
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem("walletconnect") !== null) {
      a();
    }
```

Your connection will stay alive and you can still do transactions